# What's the difference between ${var=default} and ${var-default}

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I see the [doc here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#FTN.AEN6310)

> ${parameter-default}, ${parameter:-default}
> If parameter not set, use default.

and

> ${parameter=default}, ${parameter:=default}
> If parameter not set, set it to default.

I did some test and didn't find and different,anything i missed?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `${parameter=default}` sets `parameter` if it was unset.

Here, `${x-foo}` leaves `x` unset:

```
; unset x
; echo ${x-foo}
foo
; echo $x

;
```

But here, `${x=foo}` sets `x` to `foo`:

```
; echo ${x=foo}
foo
; echo $x
foo
;
```

Comment: so `${parameter-default}` use a `parameter` copy and did not change `parameter` it self and `${parameter=default}` use `parameter` directly （as a pointer）?

Comment: I would not describe it that way.